# Making Jenkins (Hudson) job depend on another job

Tags: hudson, build-automation, jenkins

I have two jobs:

1. *Upload*
2. *Launch-instance*

I want to make *Launch-instance* dependent on the other one, so that triggering *Launch-instance* automatically causes *Upload* to be run first.

Can I achieve this using built-in Jenkins features or with a plugin?

Note that I do **not** want *Upload* to always trigger *Launch-instance*, which is what the "Build after other projects are built" option on *Launch-instance* would do. What I want is more **analogous to how `depends` attribute works in [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html)**.

Comment: NB: you could substitute the job names with "A" and "B" without losing relevant information. :)

Comment: Upload and Launch-Instance actually makes the question more clear to me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you tried the [Parametrized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)?

You can use it as a build step, and mark the checkbox for "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds". That should be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have the time (or need) to try out the plugin right now, but yes, this looks like a good way to do it.

Comment: I have installed this plugin but the option to "Trigger/call builds on other projects" from the "Build Steps" menu is not there.

Answer (score 6):

Aha, found it! Here I'm building on **[miki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674468/making-jenkins-hudson-job-depend-on-another-job/2674978#2674978)** which showed the way but didn't fully solve this for me.

As it says in the **[Spanish-language article about launching Hudson builds](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2009/10/27/hudson-subversion-push/)** which was linked to from the comments of Hudson's [Remote access API page](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Remote+access+API) that miki linked to:

> En la sección "**Build Triggers**" [...] marcamos la
>   opción "**Trigger builds remotely (e.g.,
>   from scripts)**". Al marcar esta opción vemos como aparece el cuadro de texto "Authentication Token". Aquí pondremos el nombre del token de autenticación.

[image]
<sub>(source: [adictosaltrabajo.com](http://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/hudsonSubversionPush/hudsonSubversionPush-01.png))</sub>

(It seems the benefits of knowing Spanish are starting to materialise... :-)

So, turns out Hudson provides a handy built-in option for triggering builds remotely. In **Build Triggers** section (of *Upload* job in my case) you can **enable remote builds** and set an auth token (see screenshot above). Then you can launch a build by accessing a certain URL containing that token. In my case, the first build step of *Launch-instance* looks like:

```
wget http://[hudson-url]/job/Upload/build?token=TEST
sleep 10
```

This works even if anonymous builds are disabled and simply trying to access the build URL would yield "403 Forbidden".

Answer (score 2):

What about building *Upload* by calling its [build URL](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-Configuringautomaticbuilds) with wget as the first build step? Then adding the beef build steps of *Launch-instance*.

Or for a fancier approach, perhaps use the [Remote access API](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Remote+access+API).

Comment: +1 for leading me to the right path! Simply accessing build URL won't work in our case as anonymous builds are disabled. But I found key advice from the link Alejandro Pérez García posted in the *comments* of that "Remote access API" page. :-) I put details in separate answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674468/making-hudson-job-depend-on-another-job/2675178#2675178

Comment: I guess it's fairest to accept this answer. (Just remember to check out *Build Triggers -> Trigger builds remotely* in job configuration when security is enabled; details in my answer.)

Comment: This seems like a pretty bad idea and I wouldn't suggest this solution for other users, although it does work.  Other solutions below have more votes.

Answer (score 2):

Running dependent job via wget is not a general solution. Since jobs are run asynchornnously your Launch-job will not be hang and wait for Upload job for a completion. using sleep is just a dirty hack and is not an option for most cases... 
IMHO the best solution is to use:  http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the downstream or upstream dependencies. You should use "Build Triggers" -> 
 Build after other projects are built and/or post-build actions in the configure part of the project.

Comment: You have to add "Build-Trigger"-> Build after in the "Update" project and enter "Launch-instance" there.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't seem to read the whole question... It says I do **not** want *Upload* to always trigger *Launch-instance* (but when *Launch-instance* is run, *Upload* should be run first).