# How Can I trigger a jenkins job after successful completion of another job and both the jobs are running in different Jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-scriptler

I need to trigger a job in server1 after the successful completion of a job in Server2. Both the servers are under same domain.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674468/making-jenkins-hudson-job-depend-on-another-job ? Isn't this a similar case?

Comment: This is about triggering a job from another job. I want this to be done in between two servers. (Triggering job and the job to be triggered is in different servers)

Comment: "under same domain" could mean "Same Jenkins Operation Center", or could simply mean share some naming in common. In general if you have a secure system (and you should) you'll need to have the credentials of the "other system" to use a "Remote Job Invocation" (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359810/how-to-trigger-jenkins-builds-remotely-and-to-pass-parameters). If using Jenkins Operation Center, you can directly specify the remote job name with auto-complete options.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look to the [URLTrigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URLTrigger+Plugin) for Jenkins.

Install this plugin on the server1.

On your server1/job, please configure the build trigger like below:

[image]

When the job will be completed on the server2, the server1/job will see a change on the buildNumber attribute.
It will trigger a new build on server1.

Comment: It's strange, I did a test between my production and my staging Jenkins server and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a jenkins master, you could add the other servers as jenkins slaves and use the `node('[slave name]') { ... }` feature of the workflow plug in to start a build on that slave.

Comment: I want to trigger a job in other server and not run job in other server.

Comment: In that case you can just use `build somejob` where `somejob` is another job where you'd have `node('other server name')`

Comment: @ebnius: Make one jenkins master a slave of another jenkins master? That *might* work, but not do what the OP is asking.  He has a Job1 in JenkinsA and wants to invoke Job2 in JenkinsB.